# get everything after a particular string

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a String coming as `"process_client_123_Tree"` and `"process_abc_pqr_client_123_Tree"`. I want to extract everything after `"process_client_"` and `"process_abc_pqr_client_"` and store it in a String variable.

Here `currentKey` variable can contain either of above two strings.

```
String clientId = // how to use currentKey here so that I can get remaining portion in this variable
```

What is the right way to do this? Should I just use split here or some regex?

Comment: either:- use a Pattern or test with startswith and then substring

Comment: What is the Pattern will look like? I have a if check already with `startswith` for both of those two above strings and I need to do this inside that if block only so it looks like I can use Pattern only.

Comment: Try `String clientId = currentKey.replaceFirst("process.*client_", "");`.

Comment: @saka1029 This works as long as the desired part of the string does not contain another `client_`! `.*` is greedy and will eat into the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("^process_(client_|abc_pqr_client_)(.*)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("process_client_123_Tree");
        while(matcher.find())
            System.out.println("String 1 Group 2: "+matcher.group(2));
        matcher = pattern.matcher("process_abc_pqr_client_123_Tree");
        while(matcher.find())
            System.out.println("String 2 Group 2: "+matcher.group(2));

        System.out.println("Another way..");

        System.out.println("String 1 Group 2: "+"process_client_123_Tree".replace("process_client_", ""));
        System.out.println("String 2 Group 2: "+"process_abc_pqr_client_123_Tree".replace("process_abc_pqr_client_", ""));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ java test
String 1 Group 2: 123_Tree
String 2 Group 2: 123_Tree
Another way..
String 1 Group 2: 123_Tree
String 2 Group 2: 123_Tree
```

Regex breakup:

^                                         match start of line
process_(client_|abc_pqr_client_)         match "process_" followed by "client_" or abc_pqr_client_" (captured as group 1)
(.*)$                                     . means any char and * means 0 or more times, so it match the rest chars in string until end ($) and captures it as group 2

Comment: Thanks it works fine. Also what will be the regex for this if I want to extract everything between these two string `process_client_` and `_trace_count` inside this string `process_client_123_Tree_trace_count` so I want to extract `123_Tree` from that String.

Comment: `^process_client_(.*)_trace_count$` -- And again you only have one matching group.

Comment: `^process_client_(.*)_trace_count$` would be the regex

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Matchit{

   public static void main(String []args){
      String str = "process_abc_pqr_client_123_Tree";
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("process_abc_pqr_client_(.*)|process_client_(.*)");
      Matcher m = p.matcher("process_abc_pqr_client_123_Tree");
      if (m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
      }
   }
}
```

Gets you:

```
123_Tree
```

The parentheses in the regexp define the match groups. The pipe is a logical or. Dot means any character and star means any number. So, I create a pattern object with that regexp and then use a matcher object to get the part of the string that has been matched.

Comment: Voila the explanation, @user1803551!

Answer (score 1):

A regex pattern could be: [`"process_(?:abc_pqr_)?client_(\\w+)"`  <sup>regex101 demo</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/pF4lT3/1)

- `(?:abc_pqr_)?` is the [optional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) part
- `(?:` opens a [non capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) `)?` zero or one times
- `\w+` matches one or more [word characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

[Demo at RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/kqewq6). Matches will be in `group(1)` / first [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

---

To extend it with limit to the right, match [lazily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) up to the right token

```
"process_(?:abc_pqr_)?client_(\\w+?)_trace_count"
```

where `\w+?` matches as few as possible word characters to meet condition.